# How to retrieve zero post users in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve those **authors** that have zero or no posts in wordpress. what will be the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the magic for you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_users.id = wp_posts.post_author ) 
WHERE wp_posts.post_author IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php wp_list_authors('exclude_admin=0&hide_empty=0'); ?>`

if you set `hide_empty=1` - it will show those with 1 or more posts.

Comment: But setting hide_empty to zero forces the admin account to be listed as well. Admin should not be listed.

Comment: set `exclude_admin=1` just take this `<?php wp_list_authors('exclude_admin=1&hide_empty=0'); ?>`